# Hide Submit Button of Word Form prior to emailing

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have been building a form to make a daily task faster and easy.
The Word form allows me to fill out info for each person and i have a "SUBMIT" button at the bottom that:

- Converts active document to PDF
- Emails the PDF as an attachment

The issue I am having is i cant seem to integrate code to remove the submit button from the form prior to it getting converted to pdf and attached.  This is just an OCD cleanliness thing for me.  Any help would be appreciated as vba is not my strongest suite.

```vb
Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim OL                  As Object
    Dim EmailItem           As Object
    
    'Delcared Variables for Signature from Outlook to include images
    Dim strSignature        As String
    Dim sPath               As String
    Dim signImageFolderName As String
    Dim completeFolderPath  As String
    
    'Code needed to convert WORD file to PDF in prep for attaching to email
    strFileName = Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docm", ".pdf")
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFileName, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'Setting up Outlook to produce the email
    Set OL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set EmailItem = OL.CreateItem(0)
    
    'The main body text of the email, configured in HTML format
    strbody = "See Attached!<br><br>" & "<B>Thank You!</B><br><br>"
    
    'Gaining folder path to Outlook Signature and Signature image folder (specific to user folder and name of Outlook Signature
    sPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\Main.htm"
    signImageFolderName = "Main_files"
    completeFolderPath = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\" & signImageFolderName
    
    If Dir(sPath) <> "" Then
        strSignature = GetSignature(sPath)
        strSignature = VBA.Replace(strSignature, signImageFolderName, completeFolderPath)
    Else
        strSignature = ""
    End If
    
    'Establishing email
    With EmailItem
        .To = ""
        .CC = ""
        .Subject = "FPE Daily Priorities"
        .HTMLBody = strbody & "<br>" & strSignature
        .Importance = olImportanceNormal
        .Attachments.Add strFileName
        '.Send
        .Display
    End With
    Kill strFileName
    Set OL = Nothing
    Set EmailItem = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can format the ActiveX button as hidden text to make it disappear. Wrap the button in a bookmark for easy access:

```
ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("SubmitButton").Range.Font.Hidden = True
```

As an alternative, you could add a document-level QAT button that runs the submit macro. Then it doesn't appear on the page at all.

Comment: Thank you for the input and sorry about the delay. Could you better explain the document-level QAT button and how to implement it.

Comment: In Word for Windows, choose _File>Options>Quick Access Toolbar_. Change the _Customize Quick Access Toolbar_ dropdown to _For DocumentName.docm_, where DocumenName is the name of the file containing the macro. Then the customization travels with the document.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your button is an ActiveX control in the document surface (otherwise it's difficult to make sense of the question!), then
a. you can't delete the button in its event code
b. I don't think you can hide the button completely, e.g. using `.Backstyle = frmBackStyleTransparent` and setting `.ForeColor = &H00FFFFFF`, because a small frame remains that I can't see how to make white or transparent.

So I suspect the only thing you can do is cover the button with something the same color as the document surface behind the button (typically white, which is what I'm assuming here). I am assuming here that the button cannot move.

You can do that by inserting a rectangular shape with size and position so that it just surrounds the button. Set its shape outline to no outline and its shape fill color to white.

Let's suppose for the moment that the shape is the only Shape in the document. Then in VBA, you can surround your .ExportAsFixedFormat call like this:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Zorder msoBringInFrontOfText
ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFileName, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).Zorder msoSendBehindText
```

If it isn't the only shape in the document, you can either discover its index and use that instead of 1 or you can discover its name (using VBA) and use that as the index, or set its name. Here for example I set its name to "cover-up" and used code like this

```
Const coverUpShapeName As String = "cover-up"
' ...
ActiveDocument.Shapes(coverUpShapeName).ZOrder msoBringInFrontOfText
strFileName = Replace(ActiveDocument.FullName, ".docm", ".pdf")
    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=strFileName, _
        ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF
ActiveDocument.Shapes(coverUpShapeName).ZOrder msoSendBehindText
```

Comment: Thank you for the input and sorry about the delay. I think i will just have to deal with my OCD for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code by Ibby from the [MVP FAQ](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/HidePrintButton.htm)?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  With ActiveDocument
    .Shapes(1).Visible = msoFalse
    .PrintOut Background:=False
    .Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue
  End With

End Sub
```

This assumes that the button is an ActiveX Command Button rather than a shape.

I agree with John that a QAT icon attached to the document might be the way to go rather than a button in the document. [Modifying the Quick Action Toolbar in Microsoft Word](http://addbalance.com/word/QATmodification.htm)